# Анимация при нажатии css

Tags: javascript, css, css3, анимация

Хочу попробовать повторить анимационный эффект который, пример его по ссылке [пример](https://preply.com/repetitor/209/), при переходе с вкладки на вкладку "О репетиторе" и "отзывы" медленно появляется и исчезает нижний бордер.
Имею конструкцию

```
<div id="id1" class="class1">
</div>
<div id="id2" class="">
</div>
```

Где при клике на блок добавляю `class1` JSoм
Пробовал втупую скопировать не получилось. Читал материалы о `transition` и в основном примеры с `hover`. Подскажите пожалуйста как работать с кликом.

Comment: у вас два элемента с одинаковым `id`, так делать нельзя

Comment: Опечатка, исправил

Comment: я у себя 'каретку' использовал, смотртся поизящней и анимация работает через промежуточный таб (с 1 на 3 например)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `border` лучше использовать псевдо-элемент `after`, с ним можно придумать больше вариантов анимации

```js
const $tabs = $('.block');

$tabs.on('click', function () {
  $tabs.removeClass('active');
  
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #333;
}

.block.animation1:after {
  left: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transition: left .3s ease;
}

.block.animation2:after {
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  transition: right .3s ease;
}

.block.active:after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='block active animation1'>
  Раз Кнопка
</div>
<div class='block animation2'>
  Два Кнопка
</div>
```

Comment: На моем примере оно реверсивно, в моем случае нужно добавлять получается использование before?

Comment: @Domilola, нет это нужно явно прописать в css стилях

Comment: @Domilola, поправил пример

Answer (score 1):

В указанном выше ответе не совсем точно копирует действия из примера, так как анимация меняется в зависимости от позиции предыдущего активного пункта, то есть анимация может быть слева на право, либо наоборот. Вот примерно так (красоту оставлю на ваше усмотрение):

```js
$(function() {
  var menuItem = '.menu-item',
      $menuItem = $(menuItem);

  $menuItem.on('click', function() {
    var lastIndex = $(menuItem + '.active').index(),
        newIndex = $(this).index();
    
    $menuItem.removeClass('active active-from-left active-from-right');
    
    var className = 'active-from-right';

    if (lastIndex <= newIndex) {
        className = 'active-from-left';
    }

    $(this).addClass(className).delay(1).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        next();
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.menu-item.active-from-left.active:before {
  right: 0px;
}
.menu-item.active-from-left:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  transition: all .4s;
}
.menu-item.active-from-right.active:before {
  left: 0;
}
.menu-item.active-from-right:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  transition: all .4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='menu-item active active-from-left'>Пункт 1</div>
<div class='menu-item'>Пункт 2</div>
<div class='menu-item'>Пункт 3</div>
```

Comment: упс, ответ уже поправили.